# How to ignore a string that includes a '+'

Tags: linux, unix, grep

The issue may be the fact that I am ignoring multiple strings, but here is what I'm doing at the moment:

```
grep -Ev 'lost+found|controller|config'
```

All lines with 'controller' and 'config' are being ignored, but all lines with 'lost+found' are still appearing. Is there a workaround to ignore strings that include the '+' symbol?

Comment: Escape the `+`: `\+`.

Comment: You need to learn what characters have special meaning in regular expressions, and escape them if you want them to be treated literally.

Comment: `+` is a literal when `grep` uses basic regular expression. But `-E` turns `extended regular expression` on. This gives meaning to `+` which is 1 or more occurrence of the previous expression.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What special characters must be escaped in regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399078/what-special-characters-must-be-escaped-in-regular-expressions)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dealing with `lost+found|controller|config`:

`lost+found` matches 1 or more occurrences of `t` in `lostttt`.

As @zwer and @Barmar mention, a `+` indicates repetition.

Effectively, what is matched is:

[image]

Changing the `+` to a `\+` (escaping the special character) now matches what you need:

[image]

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/) is a great resource to explore what your regex does:

[image]